ag-grid (angular) - How to span a column header over two columns?
I'm trying to setup a grid using ag-grid angular.   I want to span a single column header over two columns.
|    spans col 1 and 2    |   <- header row
| row 1 col1 | row 1 col2 |   <- data row 1
| row 2 col1 | row 2 col2 |   <- data row 2


I've read about column groups, but that seems to add a 2nd header row which can span two column headers.  I don't want this.
|   group spans col 1 and 2   |   <- group header row
| col 1 header | col 2 header |   <- column header row (don't want this)
|  row 1 col1  |  row 1 col2  |   <- data row 1
|  row 2 col1  |  row 2 col2  |   <- data row 2


Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?
EDIT:  Can I accomplish this and retain the ability to sort, filter, etc. . . . the features available to headers?
Based on @Eugene's answer below, I would want standard header behavior, at least for unspanned columns.  Can I sort or filter col 3?  It would be cool if I could provider a sort functor for how to sort the group of col 1 and 2.
|   group spans col 1 and 2   | col 3 group  |  <- group header row
| col 1 header | col 2 header | col 3 header |  <- column header row (hidden with [headerHeight]="0")
|  row 1 col1  |  row 1 col2  |  row 1 col3  | <- data row 1
|  row 2 col1  |  row 2 col2  |  row 2 col3  | <- data row 2



You can use group header with headerHeight and groupHeaderHeight options:
<ag-grid-angular
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [headerHeight]="0"
  [groupHeaderHeight]="48"
/>

public columnDefs: (ColDef | ColGroupDef)[] = [
  {
    headerName: "Header Name",
    children: [
      { field: "field1" },
      { field: "field2" },
    ],
  },
  { field: "field3" },
];

Plunker Example


I assume that "group header" is the same as "column groups"?  https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-groups/
If so, in this approach can I still sort, filter, etc from the exposed group header, at least for ungrouped coluns?  I edited my post to include a col3 to illustrate this question better.

@Jobu yes, you can use ColGroupDef at the same level as ColDef and achieve the desired result. I'll update my answer.

Got it.   Is there any way to put the sorter on the ColGroupDef?  for example to sort Athlete Details by name?  Not required, but I'm curious.

I think, depending on the task, you can try not using ColGroupDef and instead use cellRenderer to place information from different fields in one cell.

Yes, as long as there's a noWrap that is strictly honored then I bet it makes more sense for me to do use a cellRendered and comparator for this case.
